# Cannot find function createEvent in object

Tags: calendar

I have no idea why I am getting this error...  All of the other code in this script is commented out...
Any help would be appreciated!

error message: TypeError: Cannot find function createEvent in object . (line 16, file "Code")

```
function createEvent(test) 
{
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(test);
var title = 'Script Demo Event';
var start = new Date("April 5, 2013 08:00:00 PDT");
var end = new Date("April 5, 2013 10:00:00 PDT");
var desc = "Created using Google Apps Script";
var loc = "Script Center";
var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {description:desc, location:loc});
};
```

Comment: add flags to specify the language/technology you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(friend figured it out)
These two do not play well together....

createEvent AND getCalendarsByName

createEvent must use getCalendarsByID